# How to check 2 conditions in a try block before executing catch block - Selenium WebDriver Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, exception

I want to check 2 states (conditions) of a single function in a try block before going to catch block.

I have a search functionality, that holds true for one of the two following webdriver waits as long as the functionality works properly.

```
1. new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(kenshoSearchVerify));
2. new WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(kenshoNoResultVerify));
```

I have a test where user enters the term in the box, if result exist for the search term, then 1 holds true, and if no result exist then 2 holds true.

Now I want to add a third option here, to check if the search functionality is broken or not, whether it is finding one of the above two waits or not.

I have my function like this,

```
public void kenshoSearch(String searchTerm) throws Exception
    {

        driver.findElement(kenshoSearchBox).sendKeys(searchTerm);
        try{
            new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(kenshoSearchVerify));
            new WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(kenshoNoResultVerify));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Assert.fail("Something's wrong with the search!");
        }

    }
```

How can I check the two waits in try block before moving forward to catch block? The above code is clearly wrong in the try block.

Comment: Not. you are going to the catch block as soon as an Exception is thrown. If the first 'Wait' instantiation throws an Exception, you'll immediately go to the catch block. You won't instantiate the second one, so you won't be able to perform any tests on it anyway.

Comment: You could use several try-catch blocks, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of catching exceptions, have you tried something like this? I'm assuming the waits aren't really necessary... but they may be.

```
public void kenshoSearch(String searchTerm) throws Exception
{
    driver.findElement(kenshoSearchBox).sendKeys(searchTerm);
    if (driver.findElements(kenshoSearchVerify).isEmpty() && driver.findElements(kenshoSearchVerify).isEmpty())
    {
        Assert.fail("Something's wrong with the search!");
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked your way as well , plus , yes waits are important in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick:

```
public void kenshoSearch(String searchTerm) throws Exception
{

    driver.findElement(kenshoSearchBox).sendKeys(searchTerm);
    try{
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(kenshoSearchVerify));
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        try{
           new WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(kenshoNoResultVerify));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
              Assert.fail("Something's wrong with the search!");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If an exception is thrown in that statement,you still will be kicked in the catch before any check could be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure at all, try

```
    try {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
            .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
                By.All(kenshoSearchVerify, kenshoNoResultVerify)));
    }
```